# How can I set the MaximumSize on a JDialog?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I tried to do something like:

```
  public static void main(final String[] args)
  {
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog();

    dialog.add(new JButton("XXXXXXX"));
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    dialog.setSize(new Dimension(100,100));

    dialog.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,100));
  }
```

But I can still resize this dialog above the 100,100 limit I set.  Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: How about using `setResizable(false)` instead?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad I need them to be able to resize it just not above a certain height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter()
{
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent event)
    {
        setSize(100,100);
    }
});
```

Comment: +1, Although since OP is not extending `JDialog`, OP will need declare `dialog` as `final`.